# Can't plot the scatter plot using Cartopy which well shown in basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

The [HDF-EOS](https://hdfeos.org/zoo/index_openGESDISC_Examples.php) website presents some useful code examples to process satellite data. I tried to utilize the OMI-based level2 retrieved datasets (swap-like). However, when I want to visualize the data using Cartopy which I though was better than basemap in Python, issue arise.

Here is the example code. I have uploaded the case data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R71zoRw2Vc4scxF0LtrAQ_u2qrHRVeGP), anyone interested can download it.

```
## related libraries
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import cartopy
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import StamenTerrain
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


## read the data
dset = f[DATAFIELD_NAME]
data = dset[:]
lat = f[LAT_NAME][:]
lon = f[LON_NAME][:]
title = dset.attrs['Title'].decode()
units = dset.attrs['Units'].decode()
_FillValue = dset.attrs['_FillValue']
add_offset = dset.attrs['Offset']
scale_factor = dset.attrs['ScaleFactor']
data[data == _FillValue] = np.nan
data = data * scale_factor + add_offset
data = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(data), data)
# Subset data at nCandidate = 0
data = data[0,:,:]
lon = lon[0,:,:]
lat = lat[0,:,:]
```

```
fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',
                llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat = 90,
                llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon = 180)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 120., 30.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180., 45.), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1])
m.scatter(lon, lat, c=data, s=0.1, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
          edgecolors=None, linewidth=0)
cb = m.colorbar()
cb.set_label(units)
plt.title("BASEMAP")

ax2 = plt.subplot(122,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2.scatter(lon,lat,c=data,s=0.1,zorder =4,\
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = plt.cm.jet)
ax2.set_global()
plt.title("CARTOPY")
```

[image]

I don't know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you make this reproducible without needing to download anything?

Comment: OK, I tried to copy the data here.

Comment: Does `transform=ccrs.Geodetic()` change anything? What are the bounds for your longitude and latitude data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your example is not working, I can get a figure using the following code that is basically the same as yours:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

FILE_NAME = 'OMI-Aura_L2G-OMNO2G_2016m0526_v003-2016m0527t184011.he5'
path = '/HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields/'
DATAFIELD_NAME = path + 'ColumnAmountNO2'


f=h5py.File(FILE_NAME, mode='r')
dset = f[DATAFIELD_NAME]
data =dset[:].astype(np.float64)

# Retrieve any attributes that may be needed later.
# String attributes actually come in as the bytes type and should
# be decoded to UTF-8 (python3).
scale = f[DATAFIELD_NAME].attrs['ScaleFactor']
offset = f[DATAFIELD_NAME].attrs['Offset']
missing_value = f[DATAFIELD_NAME].attrs['MissingValue']
fill_value = f[DATAFIELD_NAME].attrs['_FillValue']
title = f[DATAFIELD_NAME].attrs['Title'].decode()
units = f[DATAFIELD_NAME].attrs['Units'].decode()

# Retrieve the geolocation data.
latitude = f[path + 'Latitude'][:]
longitude = f[path + 'Longitude'][:]

latitude=latitude[0,:,:]
longitude=longitude[0,:,:]
data=data[0,:,:]

data[data == missing_value] = np.nan
data[data == fill_value] = np.nan
data = scale * (data - offset)
datam = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(data), data)

#Figure
fig=plt.figure()
axs=plt.subplot(111,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
pcm=axs.scatter(longitude,latitude,c=datam,s=0.1,cmap='viridis',norm=LogNorm(vmin=1e14,vmax=1e17))
axs.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
#colorbar
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.87)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.89, 0.3, 0.04, 0.4])
cbar=fig.colorbar(pcm,cax=cbar_ax, extend='both', orientation='vertical')
```

this is the result:
[image]

I used a log color scale and set some reasonable values for your colorscale to make the plot readable. In addition I used viridis color map because [jet is not a perceptually uniform colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), and **it should not be used**!

p.s.
It took a while for me to load your dataset because your example is not clear at all. For example you didn't specify which datafield were you plotting or how to read in the dataset. Try to edit your question to make it more clear!